# symfony2 get login username while encoding password

Tags: symfony, passwords, encode, fosuserbundle

Hi i am gooling but without result.

I am trying to check one field in DB while encoding password to user. How?

```
The service 

services:
my_password_encoder:
    class: TB\WelcomePageBundle\Security\Encoder\MyPasswordEncoder  

<?php

namespace TB\WelcomePageBundle\Security\Encoder;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\BasePasswordEncoder;
use TB\UserBundle\Entity\User;

class MyPasswordEncoder extends BasePasswordEncoder
{    
public function encodePassword($raw, $salt)
{      
    $user = new User;
    $old_or_new=$user->getOldNew();
    print_r($user);
    print_r($old_or_new);die();
```

The point: 
1. withdrawn one field from DB from current logging user.
2. Depend on the value i need: encode his password MY WAY and log in + CHANGE THE PASSWORD THE SYMFONY WAY and update DB. 
3. Depend on the value just use the symfony way.

There is easy condition. The problem is just how i can withdrawn this field + encode password symfony way. (how encode password my way i know). + encode the password not more via my way but symfony and update DB.

My points is to migrate low secure passwords to symfony2. Why? Because i have existing DB where the passwords are encoded my way. So i need to "update" them.

---

THE MAIN PART OF QUESTION:

HOW CAN I GET THE USERNAME OF USER WHO TRY LOG IN IN ENCODE PASSWORD FUNCTION??? THX!!!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Also please limit your post to one question, you can make a seperate post for your second question.

Comment: i updated the post. Hope that now it's clear.

Comment: ah i am so on tilt! i dont know just how to get the username who is logging in :/ If i would know i could use fosusermanager and retriewe data from DB to it.

Comment: You probably want to use two different User classes, with each his own encoder.